# Dynamically filtering a column/property in to an EF 4.1 query using C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to create a generic "search engine" in C# using linq. I have a simple search engine that functions and look like the following.

```
var query = "joh smi";
var searchTerms = query.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
var numberOfTerms = searchTerms.Length;

var matches = from p in this.context.People
              from t in searchTerms
              where p.FirstName.Contains(t) ||
              p.LastName.Contains(t)
              group p by p into g
              where g.Count() == numberOfTerms
              select g.Key;
```

I want it to be more generic so I can call it like this:

```
var matches = Search<Person>(dataset, query, p => p.FirstName, p => p.LastName);
```

I've gotten as far as the following, but it fails with a "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." System.NotSupportedException.

```
static IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(IQueryable<T> items, string query,
                              params Func<T, string>[] properties)
{
    var terms = query.Split(' ');
    var numberOfParts = terms.Length;

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var transformed = items.SelectMany(item => terms, 
                (item, term) => new { term, item });

                                              // crashes due to this method call
        var filtered = transformed.Where(p => prop(p.item).Contains(p.term));
        items = filtered.Select(p => p.item);
    }

    return from i in items
           group i by i into g
           where g.Count() == numberOfParts
           select g.Key;
}
```

I'm certain it's doable, there just has to be a way to compile `i => i.FirstName` to an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, but that's where my LINQ expertise ends. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Predicate Builder to construct your `Or` query, something like:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    Func<T, string> currentProp = prop;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => currentProp(p.item).Contains(p.term));
}
var result = items.Where(predicate );
```

Comment: This still doesn't allow Linq-to-Entities to expand the expression 
   p => currentProp(p.item).Contains(p.term)

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a Specification Pattern. Check out [this blog](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/). Specifically, look at the spec pattern he developed. This is a similar thought to @Variant where you can build a dynamic specification and pass it to your context or repository.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the content of the queries just needed to be 'Expanded'. I used a library I found [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx) to expand the expressions. I think that allows Linq to Entities to translate it in to sql. You'll notice Expand gets called over and over again; I think all of them are necessary. It works, anyway. Code to follow:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class SearchEngine<T>
{
    class IandT<T>
    {
        public string Term { get; set; }
        public T Item { get; set; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Find(
                  IQueryable<T> items,
                  string query,
                  params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] properties)
    {
        var terms = query.Split(new char[] { ' ' },
                                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var numberOfParts = terms.Length;

        Expression<Func<IandT<T>, bool>> falseCond = a => false;
        Func<Expression<Func<IandT<T>, bool>>,
             Expression<Func<IandT<T>, bool>>,
             Expression<Func<IandT<T>, bool>>> combineOr = 
                (f, g) => (b) => f.Expand(b) || g.Expand(b);

        var criteria = falseCond;

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            var currentprop = prop;
            Expression<Func<IandT<T>, bool>> current = c => 
                    currentprop.Expand(c.Item).IndexOf(c.Term) != -1;
            criteria = combineOr(criteria.Expand(), current.Expand());
        }

        return from p in items.ToExpandable()
               from t in terms
               where criteria.Expand(new IandT<T> { Item = p, Term = t })
               group p by p into g
               where g.Count() == numberOfParts
               select g.Key;
    }
}
```

It can be called via the following code:

```
var matches = Search<Person>(dataset, query, p => p.FirstName, p => p.LastName);
```